# C++ no matching function for call error (defaulting to pass by reference)

Tags: c++, graph, compiler-errors, pass-by-reference, dijkstra

I am currently working on a program that uses dijkstra's algorithm with graphs. I was given a function that is supposed to get adjacent vertices of a specified vertex defined here in the `Graph` class as:

```
template<class VertexType>
void Graph<VertexType>::GetToVertices(VertexType vertex, Queue<VertexType>& adjvertexQ) const
{
    int fromIndex;
    int toIndex;
    fromIndex = IndexIs(vertex);
    for (toIndex = 0; toIndex < numVertices; toIndex++)
    if (edges[fromIndex][toIndex] != NULL_EDGE)
        adjvertexQ.enqueue(vertices[toIndex]);
}
```

I am trying to use this function in my client file `dijkstra.cpp` as follows:

```
void assignWeights(Graph<string> &dGraph, int numVertices, VertexType myVertices[], int startingLocation, Queue<string>& getTo)
{
    int currV = startingLocation;

    dGraph.GetToVertices(myVertices[startingLocation],adjvertexQ);

}
```

The variable `myVertices` is an array of structs defined in main containing information about each vertex and of type `VertexType` and `adjvertexQ` is a Queue of `VertexType` objects that is used to keep track of the adjacent vertices.

Errors given:

```
dijkstra.cpp: error: no matching function for call to ‘Graph<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::GetToVertices(VertexType&, Queue<VertexType>&)’

graph.cpp: note: candidates are: void Graph<VertexType>::GetToVertices(VertexType, Queue<VertexType>&) const [with VertexType = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >]
```

The problem seems to be that I am passing the `VertexType` variable by reference, but even when I use a temp value inside the same method it still recognizes the parameter as a pass by reference value. Any idea of what might fix this?

Comment: Sorry, I should've elaborated more on `VertexType`. It is a structs that contains the following: `string name` for the name of the vertex, `bool marked`, to check if that vertex has been checked already, `int distance`, to check the distance btw this vertex and the previous and `string previous` for the previous vertex.

Comment: I expanded my (now deleted) comment below to an answer. (Knowing the content of VertexType is nice, but doesn´t change it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´m assuming `assignWeights` is not part of the `Graph` class.

Passing by reference/value/anything isn´t the problem here,
but you´re confusing your different VertexTypes.

a) You have a function

```
void assignWeights(Graph<string> &dGraph, int numVertices, VertexType myVertices[], int startingLocation, Queue<string>& getTo)
```

where `VertexType` is a class, struct, or typedef somewhere else.

b) And you have a class method

```
template<class VertexType>
void Graph<VertexType>::GetToVertices(VertexType vertex, Queue<VertexType>& adjvertexQ) const
```

where `VertexType` is a template type. This means, a `Graph<VertexType>` has a method

```
GetToVertices(VertexType vertex, Queue<VertexType>& adjvertexQ) const
```

but a `Graph<string>` like used as parameter in `assignWeights` has a method

```
GetToVertices(string vertex, Queue<string>& adjvertexQ) const
```

...

So, in `assignWeights`, you have a `Graph<string>` with a `GetToVertices` wanting strings,
but you´re passing a variable of your VertexType class.

The copied code isn´t compatible to how your program is build
(or you´re confused with your own code)

Comment: That seemed to be the problem thank you. Just to get the answer straight:
Since in the function `GetToVertices` in my implementation file is defined a template and my function inside my client file `assignWeights` has a graph that uses strings the the function in my implementation changes to fit the parameters being able to be passed by those of `assignWeights`?

Comment: `GetToVertices` doesn´t adapt to `assignWeights`, but to the string of `Graph<string>` (or whatever is between `<>`). VertexType in Graph is just a placeholder for the thing between `<>`, and it has nothing to do with your struct. But assignWeights is using the struct, and is trying to feed it to a part of `Graph<string>`. ...